# A Windows Service to Send Emails

Tags: c#, email, windows-services

I want to create a Windows service in C# that monitors certain performance (CPU usage, Memory usage) and environmental factors (Disk space) on a server. If any problems arise it should email the administrator of the server.

The server has access to the internet.

Could anyone offer the guidance on how can I go about implementating such a service ?

Comment: This has definitely been done before. Not that I'm against developing something yourself you can probably just buy something cheaply to do this, or find something open source.

Comment: Windows has built-in functionality to do this; although it may not be versatile enough. You should be able to apply the concepts of [KB310490](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310490) to Server 2008.

Comment: Alternatively there are probably some fairly cheap/free 3rd party products but it sounds like an interesting project although could be a lot of effort to accomplish simple things, so not the most rewarding!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are asking...

- For the mail sending part you can [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx)
- For the "health monitoring" you will need to dig deep - [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404655%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) / [SNMP](http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/) etc.